# C# Accessing Windows 10 Printer Icons

Tags: c#, .net, icons, printers

Is it possible to grab "custom" printer icons like the ones on the multi-printers (the 3 visible in the picture) in Windows 10? I've had a look in shell32.dll and DDORes.dll but can't see the multifunction printer icons in there. Where are they stored? If it is possible to grab them from somewhere, is it possible to read which icon the printer should be using with WMI or something else?

[image: Device Manager Printers]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @JohnB I have no code, this is an information request. I have stated that I looked in the shell32.dll and DDORes.dll files which sometimes contain windows related icons but could not find the multifunction printer icons in them. I really don't know what else I can say. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image locations can be found in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataCache\dmrccache\en-US when using Windows 10. I had found info regarding the Windows 7 location which is slightly different to how it is now.